# Program Stops at the Beginning of Program (no bracket problems I could find)

Tags: java

My program stops right after

```
System.out.println("Would you like to calculate simple interest or compound interest?"); 

userInputStr = myScanner.next();
```

and there are no bracket problems I could find. I know it has something to do with brackets but i couldn't find it. Any suggestions?

This is my code (i will implement methods later)

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interest

{

    static double userInputDou;

    static String userInputStr;

    static double rate;

    static double time;

    static double principal;

    static double interest;

    static double subinterest;

    static double cNum;

    static double total;

    static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate simple interest or compound interest?");

        userInputStr = myScanner.next();

        if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest"))

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter the rate: ");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                rate = userInputDou;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter a integer for the rate.");

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter the time: ");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                time = userInputDou;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time.");

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter the principal: ");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                principal = userInputDou;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the principal.");

            }

            interest = (principal * rate * time);

            System.out.println("Your interest is $" + interest);

            System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + (interest + principal));

        }

        else if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("compound interest"))

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter the rate: ");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                rate = userInputDou;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter a integer for the rate.");

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter the time: ");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                time = userInputDou;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time.");

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter the principal: ");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                principal = userInputDou;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the principal.");

            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to compound the interest quarterly or annually?");

            userInputStr = myScanner.next();

            if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("quarterly"))

            {

                System.out.println("For how many quarters would you like to compound the interest for?");

                if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                {

                    userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                    cNum = (userInputDou * 4);

                    subinterest = (principal * (1 + (rate / cNum)));

                    interest = Math.pow(subinterest, time);

                    total = (principal + interest);

                    System.out.println("Your quarterly compounded interest is $" + interest);

                    System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + total);

                }

                else

                {

                    System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the number of quarters.");

                }

            }

            else if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("annually"))

            {

                System.out.println("For how many years would you like to compound the interest for?");

                if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                {
                    userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                    cNum = userInputDou;

                    subinterest = (principal * (1 + (rate / cNum)));

                    interest = Math.pow(subinterest, time);

                    total = (principal + interest);

                    System.out.println("Your annually compounded interest is $" + interest);

                    System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + total);

                }

                else

                {

                    System.out.println("Please enter an integer fro the number of years.");

                }

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter either 'quarterly' or 'annually'.");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to reformat your code, fixing the indentation and removing all the unnecessary blank lines. That would make your code a lot more readable for anyone inclined to try and help you.

Comment: When prompted, what did you type in the console before hitting enter?

Comment: @takendarkk i entered "simple".

Comment: @khelwood i put extra spaces so the program doesn't look congested, but if fit helps you, sure.

Comment: Yes, please. The whitespace is horrible.

Comment: @ HovercraftFullOfEels nextLine() doesn't help. i know that there is no problem with the actual code (as far as i know); its probable the brackets.

Comment: Daniel, Let's work this out just to make sure. I have a simple request of you: please print out the String that you obtain with your first call to `next()`, again, it would be `System.out.println(userInputStr);`. Enter two words such as, simple interest, And then tell me -- is the println printing out one word or two?

Comment: it is printing only one word: "simple" when i entered "sipmle interest"

Comment: So..... if you use `nextLine()`... you then see "simple interest", correct? And if so, you have to admit that this is a problem that you must recognize, and that one possible solution is to use nextLine, since you're testing for two-word Strings in your if blocks.

Comment: yes, it works, but what does this have to do with the program stopping? it still stops.

Comment: Again, look at my answer. Assume that the user enters "simple interest" and we know that the userInputStr variable holds "simple" and only simple, your code logic boils down to two if blocks, one that checks userInputStr against "simple interest" followed by an if else that checks it against "compound interest". Since it fails both tests the program doesn't "stop", it ends.

Comment: The solution is to 1) either get the full String into the userInputStr variable, or 2) simplify the test conditions. It might even be easier to ask the user to enter a number correspond with either `1) simple interest`, or `2) compound interest`. It's simple to get a single number entry from the user and much less prone to typing error.

Comment: Thanks. i think i get it now

Comment: ya. the nextLine() works and there are no problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myScanner.next()` will only get **one** token, meaning it will get the first word in the line but will not get multiple words, and you're checking for multiple words:

```
if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest"))
```

For instance, if you run this:

```
    System.out.println("Would you like to calculate simple interest or compound interest?");
    userInputStr = myScanner.next();

    System.out.println(userInputStr); // !!
```

If the user enters "simple interest" you'll see that `userInputStr` holds only one word, "simple". So your entire application will exit since at its most basic, your application is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to calculate simple interest or compound interest?");
    userInputStr = myScanner.next();

    System.out.println(userInputStr); // !!

    if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest")) {
        // .... do some stuff
    } else if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("compound interest")) {
        // .... do other stuff
    }
}
```

and so if the userInputStr can't possibly match either two-word String, the application will simply exit.

One way for this to work is to use `myScanner.nextLine()` as this will get the entire line of user input.

So change:

```
userInputStr = myScanner.next();
if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest"))
```

to:

```
userInputStr = myScanner.nextLine();
if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest"))
```

But note that this will add another problem, in that `nextLine()` will also get any un-swallowed end-of-line tokens that may be left dangling when you  call `myScanner.next()` or `myScanner.nextDouble()` or `myScanner.nextInt()` or most any `myScanner.nextXxx()` other than `myScanner.nextLine()`. For this reason any time you call `myScanner.nextDouble()`, call `myScanner.nextLine()` immediately after to swallow the end-of-line token.

So, for instance, change:

```
userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();
rate = userInputDou;
```

into:

```
userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();
myScanner.nextLine(); // swallow the end-of-line token
rate = userInputDou;
```

---

For Alexander's benefit, please run this code and enter "Hello World"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a multi-word sentence: ");
        String input = myScanner.next();
        System.out.println("Output: " + input);

        myScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are wrong scanner.next() gets a whole string not a single token. His first usage of next() is correct. he does not need nextLine there.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov To quote the documentation for the `next()` method in `Scanner`: "Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.". The default delimiter is whitespace, so his code will only get the first word of the input. He is then checking if it matches two words, so yes, he does need to change it to `scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: The definition of token means one character in the dictionary. I am not native so I presume that you mean by token until you terminate input.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: no, `next()` only gets the next token. Test my code or your own to see. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: token in the case of Scanner means the group characters separated by delimiter. No one's accusing you of being naive, but in this case you are wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov just because the definition of token in a dictionary that you read is "one character" does not mean it applies here

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels No need to discuss my english skills here. I understand your definition of token. I was translating it into character.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: let's not debate. Please see my edit above for your benefit, run the code and tell me what you see.

Comment: I have nothing to benefit from it. It is clear as a sun.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov then please humor me and still run the code. It's for **my** benefit then. If I'm wrong, then I'll learn.

Answer (score 1):

`userInputStr = myScanner.next()` waits for input from the console. You need to type something in. It is quite normal that is blocking.

Based on your comment entered  "simple" and hit entered. I can say that this string "simple" did not made true any of the top level comparisons you have "userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest")"   and   "else if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("compound interest"))"

and the program terminated. You need to type in either "simple interest" or "compound interest" to see any further activity.

Comment: i typed in "simple" and hit 'enter' but the program stopped and exited.

Comment: Did you try to debug ? To see on which line it terminated, or if there are any exceptions ?

Comment: See my edited answer based on your "typed simple and hit enter".

Comment: replace userInputStr = myScanner.next() with userInputStr = myScanner.nextLine()

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` of scanner .

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test

{

```
static double userInputDou;

static String userInputStr;

static double rate;

static double time;

static double principal;

static double interest;

static double subinterest;

static double cNum;

static double total;

static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)

{

    System.out.println("Would you like to calculate simple interest or compound interest?");

    userInputStr = myScanner.nextLine();

    if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest"))

    {

        System.out.println("Please enter the rate: ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

        {

            userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

            rate = userInputDou;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter a integer for the rate.");

        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the time: ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

        {

            userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

            time = userInputDou;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time.");

        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the principal: ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

        {

            userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

            principal = userInputDou;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the principal.");

        }

        interest = (principal * rate * time);

        System.out.println("Your interest is $" + interest);

        System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + (interest + principal));

    }

    else if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("compound interest"))

    {

        System.out.println("Please enter the rate: ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

        {

            userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

            rate = userInputDou;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter a integer for the rate.");

        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the time: ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

        {

            userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

            time = userInputDou;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time.");

        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the principal: ");

        if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

        {

            userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

            principal = userInputDou;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the principal.");

        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to compound the interest quarterly or annually?");

        userInputStr = myScanner.next();

        if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("quarterly"))

        {

            System.out.println("For how many quarters would you like to compound the interest for?");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                cNum = (userInputDou * 4);

                subinterest = (principal * (1 + (rate / cNum)));

                interest = Math.pow(subinterest, time);

                total = (principal + interest);

                System.out.println("Your quarterly compounded interest is $" + interest);

                System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + total);

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the number of quarters.");

            }

        }

        else if (userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("annually"))

        {

            System.out.println("For how many years would you like to compound the interest for?");

            if (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {
                userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                cNum = userInputDou;

                subinterest = (principal * (1 + (rate / cNum)));

                interest = Math.pow(subinterest, time);

                total = (principal + interest);

                System.out.println("Your annually compounded interest is $" + interest);

                System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + total);

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer fro the number of years.");

            }

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter either 'quarterly' or 'annually'.");

        }

    }

}
```

}